# Storing all text content in a single db table

Tags: database-design, multilingual

I'm building a multilingual website.

I've been thinking about using a single table for all text content `texts(key, language, content)` that other tables can refer to.

For example, let's say I have a table `items(id, name, description)`. Instead of storing actual content, the `name` and the `description` columns store references to the texts table.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think two tables in this simple case is unnecessary: you would still have a normalized design with one table, `items(id, language, text, content)`, with `(id, language)` as the primary key.

Note that if you wanted to add non-localized fields (e.g., price in dollars), then you would want two tables:

`items(id, priceInDollars)`

`itemTexts(itemId, language, name, description)`

with `id` the primary key of items, `(itemId, language)` the primary key of `itemTexts`, and `itemID` a foreign key reference to `id` in the `items` table.

Comment: Agreed, but if the same text is likely to appear in more than one item, then factoring out the text into a separate table could improve performance and simplify updates.